# How to stick a background behind the navbar?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navbar

I have a problem here.
I'm using wordpress and I was confused.
How to stick background behind the nav bar?.
I activated LowerMedia Sticky.js menu's plugin, then I want to change my navbar background color. I try to add a `background: #000;` in `#navigation`. It's look okay, but when I scroll down, the navigation background is not move. There's only the navigation text that moved. I try to move `background: #000;` to `#navigation .sf-menu a` but the background is only appear around the text, even it move with the text when I scroll down. I don't know what to do now. Please help me. Thanks before.

This is my site : [vitraprawira.net](http://www.vitraprawira.net)

This is my final navbar css code:

```
/* Main Navigation

================================================== */
/*hide responsive nav*/

#top-bar .selector, #navigation .selector { display: none; }

/*core*/

.sf-menu, .sf-menu * { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }

.sf-menu { line-height: 1.0 }

.sf-menu ul { position: absolute; top: -999em; width: 180px; }

.sf-menu ul li { width: 100% }

.sf-menu li:hover { visibility: inherit }

.sf-menu li { float: left; position: relative; }

.sf-menu a { display: block; position: relative; }

.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul { left: 0px; top: 30px; z-index: 99; }

ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul, ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul { top: -999em }

ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul, ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul { left: 180px; top: 1px; }

/*styling*/


#navigation-wrap { position: relative; display: block; }

#navigation { margin-left: 170px; margin-right: auto; position: relative; height: 55px; transparent: none; }

#navigation .sf-menu > li:hover > ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover > ul { top: 50px }

#navigation ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul, ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul, ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul, ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul { left: 200px; top: 0; }

#navigation .sf-menu a { font-size: 1.000em; height: 55px; line-height: 55px; color: #fff;  background: #000 url("images/vintage.png"); }

#navigation .sf-menu > li > a { border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }

#navigation .sf-menu li { float: left; position: relative; }

#navigation .sf-menu > li { background: url("images/dash.png") right center no-repeat; margin-right: 20px; padding-right: 20px; }

#navigation .sf-menu > li:last-child { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#navigation .sf-menu > li > a:hover { color: #fff }

#navigation .sf-menu > .current-menu-item > a { color: #7094DB }

#navigation .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a { color: #fff }

/*drop-down styles*/

#navigation .sf-menu ul { position: absolute; nowhitespace: afterproperty; top: -999em; width: 200px; z-index: 9999; left: 0; border: 1px solid #ddd; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.08); }

#navigation .sf-menu ul > li:last-child { -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; }

#navigation .sf-menu ul li { background: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05); }

#navigation .sf-menu ul li:first-child { border-top: 0 }

#navigation .sf-menu ul li:last-child { border-bottom: 0 }

#navigation .sf-menu ul a { display: block; padding: 10px; color: #fff; height: auto; margin: 0px; border: 0px; line-height: 1.8em; font-size: 0.923em; text-shadow: none; }

#navigation .sf-menu ul li > a:hover { color: #7094DB; background: #2D3B58; }
```

Comment: try to put you image #navigation {
    background-image: url("path to image");
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: I did, but when I scrolled down the background is stay on it place and not stick with the text. Actually I'm using sticky.js. Thanks for help me anyway.

Comment: Try adding your background to this class instead `.lowermedia_add_sticky`

Comment: Now its tottaly works. Thank You very much gtr1971. Nice to know You.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting the color/image to appear behind the entire menu block, then you're localizing the background too close to the anchor element.

Just do this: `#navigation {background: #ccc;}` or whatever color you want.

Comment: I try it, but it not works properly with my sticky.js. The background is stay on it place. I want it stick on the top with the text when I scroll down. Thank for Your help by the way. :)

Comment: I looked at the source of your page and I'm not seeing the sf-menu plugin nor do I see any elements with the classes. Are you sure you have the plugin activated?

Comment: Yes, the plugin is alright. I visit my website and scroll it down, the text is moving. It works like i want. I'm using wordpress by the way.